# Setting sectioned table header using nsfetchedresults controller

Tags: ios, ipad, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using NSFetchedResultsController in my project along with core data. I am able to fetch all the objects from the database. I am displaying them in a sectioned table view. I want to display the total number of rows in each section as the header of the section table view. I am not getting any kind of help for this. I have tried a lot but don't know how exactly to set it . Any kind of help is appreciable.

Comment: checkout this apple sample code might be helpful :-http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DateSectionTitles/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009939

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSInteger numberOfRows = [[[self.frc sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *sectionHeaderView = [[UITableViewHeaderFooterView alloc] init];
    sectionHeaderView.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Total objects %d", numberOfRows];

    return sectionHeaderView;
}
```

The trick is getting the right section out of the `NSFetchedResultsController` and calling the `numberOfObjects` method on it. The sections in an NSFetchedResultsController are proxy objects that conform to the [NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo) delegate.